# Checking if characters in a file can be integers

Tags: python, exception

So in a Python assignment I have to write a decoder for an mtf encoded file, which is made up of hex characters and words. In my decoder I'm reading the .mtf file char by char and checking whether or not its a letter or a hex number and I can't seem to make it work. I've erased the majority of my code to start fresh but here's the basic framework:

```
f = open(str(sys.argv[1]), "r")
new_f = str(sys.argv[1])
new_f = new_f[:len(new_f)-3]+ "txt"
f_two = open(new_f, "w")
myList = []
word = ""
words = []
index = 0


while True:
    value = None
    c = f.read(1)
    if not c:
        break
    try:
        value = int(c)

    except ValueError:
        word = word + c
```

I apologize for the horribly written code and any mistakes I may have made while writing this, this is all still relatively new to me.

Thank you!

Comment: use isdigit() function

Comment: I tried that, it still doesn't read it as in integer. Maybe I should post the sample file I'm reading from to show what I have to decode?

Comment: how would you know if an `A` is a letter or if it is a hex number using your approach?

Comment: It turns out I don't need to! Simply using ord() allows me to convert it back into an appropriate integer! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read from a file in Python, you're reading in strings. Strings also have a method called `isdigit()` which tells you if the one character is a digit or not.

```
while c:
    c = f.read(1)
    if c.isdigit():
        myList.append(c)
```

If you're checking for hex characters (0-9, A-F), you would have to build your own checking function. Something like this:

```
def is_hex(n):
    return n.isdigit() or ("A" <= n.upper() <= "F")
```